# How to prevent the logged in user to access the profile of other user by simply changing the id in url , in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am currently building a small project using Django, I have noticed a problem that a logged in user was getting access to the other users page by simply changing the  id in the url i.e
**This is the url of currently logged in user**

```
http://localhost:8000/home/myBooks/7/
```

by changing that id from 7 to 6
i.e

```
 http://localhost:8000/home/myBooks/6/
```

He was getting access to that page,I have used `@login_required` for functional based views and `LoginRequiredMixin` for class based views ,but they are not helping, what else I need to do to prevent this problem?

My app/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from . forms import BookForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . models import UserBooks
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import UserBooks
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
@login_required
def HomeView(request):
    return render(request,'home/homepage.html')
class BookDetailsView (LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model=UserBooks
    template_name='home/bookdetails.html'
class BooksView (LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
     model=User
     template_name='home/mybooks.html'

@login_required
def addBooks(request):
    if (request.method=='POST'):
        form=BookForm(data=request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            u=UserBooks()
            u.book_name=form.cleaned_data['book_name']
            u.book_author=form.cleaned_data['book_author']
            u.book_ISBN=form.cleaned_data['book_ISBN']
            u.book_status=True
            u.book_genre=form.cleaned_data['book_genre']
            u.username=request.user.username
            u.user_id = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            u.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return render (request,'home/addbooks.html',{'form':form})
```

my apps/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserBooks(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_ISBN=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_genre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    book_status=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("username", "book_ISBN"),)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name
```

my apps/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name='home'
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.HomeView,name='home'),
    path('addBooks/',views.addBooks,name='addBooks'),
    path('myBooks/<int:pk>/',views.BooksView.as_view(),name='myBooks'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.BookDetailsView.as_view(), name='myBooks'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view should always show the detail for the current user, don't put the ID in the URL at all; get the logged-in user directly within the view.

```
class BooksView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
     model = User
     template_name ='home/mybooks.html'

     def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

...

```
path('myBooks/',views.BooksView.as_view(),name='myBooks'),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just started to develop the app, then it is okay to use pks inside of urls. However, when it comes to a real working app it can lead to some security problems.

As you wrote, one can simply change the url and get some private data.

Other problems can be:

1. The number of users in the database can be easily counted by iteration through your urls.
2. The user can be easily detected by his id. Knowing it one can easily get some private data.
3. If you will decide to change ids in your db, then all the external links will be broken...and etc.

Considering that I suggest an approach in which you use ids internally. For external usage (urls, links) you can use uuids.

To do that you just need additional field into your model:

```
import uuid

uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
```

And here is the example url:

`url(r'^myBooks/(?P<user_uuid>\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\b(-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\b){3}-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}\b)/$'`,

After you switch to uuids it will be almost impossible to "hack" the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BooksView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        current_user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.pk)
        if current_user.pk == kwargs['pk']:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('profile-url')
```

Here I assume that if you are logged in user and you try to check another user profile by giving id in url. So I add a get method which will check is requested URL id is for the current user (`books/7/` is 7 is current user id) if not then redirect to an URL, for example, otherwise redirects to another url. You can get some idea. This may not help you exactly.